Not sure if a certification problem or new flutter update
This is the problem my console throws, it started the 27 of november and I am not really sure why, I did not make any major changes when it started to show this error:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
Could not resolve androidx.annotation:annotation:1.9.1.
Required by:
project :app > project :path_provider_android
> Could not resolve androidx.annotation:annotation:1.9.1.
> Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/annotation/annotation/1.9.1/annotation-1.9.1.pom'.
> Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/annotation/annotation/1.9.1/annotation-1.9.1.pom'.
> The server may not support the client's requested TLS protocol versions: (TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3). You may need to configure the client to allow other protocols to be used. See: https://docs.gradle.org/7.6.3/userguide/build_environment.html#gradle_system_properties
> PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Even if that is the error I am not sure if its related to androidx.annotation:annotation:1.9.1. or just a maven2 problem.

This issue occurs because an old version of Java is being used in the project.
Open the app/build.gradle file and make the following change within the android { block:
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_21
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_21
}


kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "21"
}

// Configure the JVM toolchain for JDK 21
java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion.set(JavaLanguageVersion.of(21))
    }
}

after this you change pls, just run flutter clean command and then make build
and also update the Kotlin and Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) versions to their latest versions

I solved it trying a lot of things, but that did not really work for my team mates with the same issue.
If they solve it with your answer I will update this question, thanks for your answer and time!!.
